# Keep original timestamps of files downloaded with nautilus

Tags: nautilus, ftp, wget

Is there a way to keep the original file date when downloading from server with nautilus ftp? Like it is now, the file has as date / time the downloaded date / time and not the one in the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a workaround, wget does that by default. From the [manpage(manual page)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/wget.1.html):

> ```
>    --timestamping
>        Turn on time-stamping.
>
>    --no-use-server-timestamps
>        Don't set the local file's timestamp by the one on the server.
>
>        By default, when a file is downloaded, it's timestamps are set to
>        match those from the remote file. This allows the use of
>        --timestamping on subsequent invocations of wget. However, it is
>        sometimes useful to base the local file's timestamp on when it was
>        actually downloaded; for that purpose, the
>        --no-use-server-timestamps option has been provided.
> ```

For nautilus, you may want to submit a bug report (feature request): https://bugzilla.gnome.org/browse.cgi?product=nautilus

Answer (score 2):

if you are likely to do from terminal , `cp` command can help you with `-p` option .

```
-p
same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps

--preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible additional attributes: context, links, all
```